# ObservableChangeSet wait until list is ready before watching

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

We have a list page where we can enable or disable a *thing*™ using a `<switch />` That *thing*™ is toggled with an IsActive flag

```cs
public class Thing
{
    /* ... */
    [Reactive] public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Given the following change listener, the idea is when the `IsActive` property changes (user interaction on a toggle switch), we invoke the `_saveItemCommand` to save the entity with the new `IsActiveState`.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Thing> DataObjectList {get;} = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();

public MyClass()
{
    _saveItemCommand  = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveItemInternal);
    _listWatcher = DataObjectList
        .ToObservableChangeSet()
        .AsObservableList()
        .Connect()
        .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.IsActive)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Select(x => x.Sender)
        .InvokeCommand(_saveItemCommand);
}

public void OnNavigatingTo()
{
    var newItems = _myService.GetNewItems();
    DataObjectList.AddRange(newItems);
}

public void OnDestroy()
{
    _listWatcher?.Dispose();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I setup the list, The command seems to be invoked on the last item in the list immediately after `AddRange` is called.

> I have tried using `.Skip(1)` without any luck, but one thing that seems to work but is ugly is `.Skip(DataObjectList.Length)`

How can I make it so that the command isn't invoked until the first time the user toggles the switch? What is the correct way to setup this listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comments on Glenn's answer and some additional conversations with Rodney, here's what finally works.

```cs
_listWatcher = DataObjectList
    .ToObservableChangeSet()
    .AsObservableList()
    .Connect()
    .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.IsActive)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
    .Skip(1)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Select(x => x.Sender)
    .InvokeCommand(_createActivationsInternal);
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you'll want to add a `Where` statement to indicate it should only be called on the IsActivated switch.

```cs
    _listWatcher = DataObjectList
        .ToObservableChangeSet()
        .AsObservableList()
        .Connect()
        .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.IsActive)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        .ToCollection()
        .Where(x => x.Any(value => value.IsActive))
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Select(x => x.Sender)
        .InvokeCommand(_saveItemCommand);
```

So the two lines I added are

```
        .ToCollection()
        .Where(x => x.Any(value => value.IsActive))
```

The `ToCollection()` will convert it into an observable list and the `Where` will restrict your observable to when there is change of the `IsActive` values.

You may wish to add a `FirstAsync()` call if you want it to happen only once after the `Where()` call.

Comment: the code I have in the original post does behave correctly as far as calling the save method when IsActive switches (it can be true or false). The issue is that it calls the save method during setup of the viewmodel instead of ONLY when the user interacts with the view.

Comment: Add a `Skip(1)` after the `Where` clause.  It's skip the first one.  You could also do
`StartWith(false).DistinctUntilChanged()`

Comment: @RodneyLittles `IsActive` can be true or false (coming from the db), and also true OR false should trigger the command. If I'm reading this correctly, the Where clause is waiting for the value to be `true`, which doesn't work.

Comment: I made a couple edits to the original question to add clarity

Comment: @ChaseFlorell This would make sense because you are skipping the first set of changes.  That was my thought about the `StartWith(false).DistinctUntilChanged()` but depending on the value that won't work. What is happening is you are emitting a change notification for everything item in the list with `WhenAnyPropertyChanged`. I know there is a way to suppress change notifications using DD, not sure how to do it from the `ObservableCollection`.

You can try `DeferUntilLoaded()` that should do the trick for the initial load.